# Class hash in PHP, to detect code changes?

Tags: php

Assume I have a system in PHP that involves class discovery.
The result of the class discovery is cached for performance.

Now I had the idea to attempt to clear or invalidate the cache, if the code changes. Either because a developer did something, or because a new version of a 3rd party library was downloaded.

One idea would be to compare file hashes for the class file. But doing this with e.g. `md5(file_get_contents($file))` seems rather costly, and not something we want to do in every request / process.

Is there another, faster way to get hash for a PHP class, that produces a different result if the code changes?

I imagine that the answer is no, but one can always ask and hope.

Comment: You can check out the speed of different hashes and use [`hash_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-file.php). You'd possibly be able to compare modification dates and sizes, too. It's how most FTP programs do it.

Comment: I haven't looked in the context of your question, but I wonder if you couldn't figure out a way using the the ReflectionClass: http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php since it is meant for getting info on PHP classes

Comment: How about just invalidating the cache on deployment?

Comment: @h2ooooooo Oh great, this is already one step better than `md5(file_get_contents())` :)

Comment: @kjones Yes obviously a `ReflectionClass::getClassHash()` would do the job, but such a method does not currently exist.

Comment: @localheinz Yes. This is what I am doing right now. I was just wondering if there is an alternative, and how expensive it would be.

Comment: @localheinz On the project I work on, clearing caches is usually quite costly, and it would slow down development doing this a lot on the local instance of the project. Time is money :)

Comment: How about invalidating and warming the cache on deployment, then? If a deployment is the only way the code can change, then it's probably the best solution to only invalidate and warm up the cache during deployment.

Comment: @localheinz It is the only way that the code can change on production. But on a local development instance, code changes all the time. And not having to clear the cache locally can save precious time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `filemtime` function to get the last modified of the file instead of checking the content of the file.
Sorry if it's not what you want to.

Comment: It clearly is or can be an improvement over `md5(file_get_contents())`. It is probably good enough for the majority of cases.

Comment: Of course it still means one has to know which file a class was defined in. `ReflectionClass::getFileName()` can do this.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697805/how-to-check-if-a-file-has-changed